# Как отправить данные методом post с помощью curl?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, curl

Нужно отправить POST запрос на URL https://integration.cdek.ru/new_orders.php с заполненной переменной xml_request, в которой передается содержимое XML фaйла.

Делаю

```
curl -X POST \
  https://integration.cdek.ru/new_orders.php \
  -H 'content-type: multipaНо выходит ошибка:rt/form-data' \
  -F 'xml_request=@<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DeliveryRequest Number="236" Date="2010-10-14" Account="abc123" Secure="abcd1234" OrderCount="2">
    <Order Number="5403" DeliveryRecipientCost="0" SendCityCode="270" RecCityCode="44" RecipientName="Васина Юлия Александровна" Phone="7810999, 9295849151" Comment="Офис группы компаний Ланит. При приезде позвонить на мобильный телефон." TariffTypeCode="5" RecientCurrency="RUB" ItemsCurrency="RUB">
        <Address PvzCode="MSK2"></Address>
        <Package Number="1" BarCode="101" Weight="630">
           <Item WareKey="25000050368" Cost="49" Payment="49" Weight="68" Amount="1" Comment="Дидактические игры-занятия в ДОУ Ст.возраст Вып. 1"></Item>
        </Package>
        <AddService ServiceCode="30"></AddService>
        <Schedule>
           <Attempt ID="1" Date="2010-10-15" TimeBeg="09:00:00" TimeEnd="13:00:00" />
           <Attempt ID="2" Date="2010-10-16" TimeBeg="14:00:00" TimeEnd="18:00:00" RecipientName="Прокопьев   Анатолий Сергеевич" />
        </Schedule>
    </Order>
</DeliveryRequest>'
```

Но выходит ошибка:

```
curl: (26) couldn't open file "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> \
<DeliveryRequest Number="236" Date="2010-10-14" Account="abc123" Secure="abcd1234" OrderCount="2">
    <Order Number="5403" DeliveryRecipientCost="0" SendCityCode="270" RecCityCode="44" Recipien
```

Как правильно записать запрос, чтобы он не пытался открыть файл?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо сменить `-F` на `-d`.

```
curl -X POST \
  https://integration.cdek.ru/new_orders.php \
  -H 'content-type: multipaНо выходит ошибка:rt/form-data' \
  -d 'xml_request=@<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DeliveryRequest Number="236" Date="2010-10-14" Account="abc123" Secure="abcd1234" OrderCount="2">
    <Order Number="5403" DeliveryRecipientCost="0" SendCityCode="270" RecCityCode="44" RecipientName="Васина Юлия Александровна" Phone="7810999, 9295849151" Comment="Офис группы компаний Ланит. При приезде позвонить на мобильный телефон." TariffTypeCode="5" RecientCurrency="RUB" ItemsCurrency="RUB">
        <Address PvzCode="MSK2"></Address>
        <Package Number="1" BarCode="101" Weight="630">
           <Item WareKey="25000050368" Cost="49" Payment="49" Weight="68" Amount="1" Comment="Дидактические игры-занятия в ДОУ Ст.возраст Вып. 1"></Item>
        </Package>
        <AddService ServiceCode="30"></AddService>
        <Schedule>
           <Attempt ID="1" Date="2010-10-15" TimeBeg="09:00:00" TimeEnd="13:00:00" />
           <Attempt ID="2" Date="2010-10-16" TimeBeg="14:00:00" TimeEnd="18:00:00" RecipientName="Прокопьев   Анатолий Сергеевич" />
        </Schedule>
    </Order>
</DeliveryRequest>'
```

Answer (score 3):

`-F` - означает файл.

кроме варианта [Andrio Skur](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/200092/andrio-skur), данные можно хранить в файле myfile.xml, а запрос составить так:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://integration.cdek.ru/new_orders.php \
  -H 'content-type: multipaНо выходит ошибка:rt/form-data' \
  -F "xml=@myfile.xml"
```